# Lotus notes views: retrieve last opened time

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there a method/trick to find when a view has been opened last time ?
In designer, if i do right click on a view, in 'info' tab there is a parameter 'Accessed' that i think correspont to that i'm loooking for.
There is a trick o method to retrive that value ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below will give the "Last Accessed" date and time for every view in your database.  Note that (according to the help file) this value is not accurate to more than 24 hours, as if a document is accessed more than once in a 24 hour period, the last accessed value is not updated.

```
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim nc As NotesNoteCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim ID As String
Dim title As string

Set db = s.Currentdatabase
Set nc = db.createNoteCollection(False)

nc.Selectviews = true
Call nc.Buildcollection()
id = nc.Getfirstnoteid()
While Not id = ""
    Set doc = db.Getdocumentbyid(id)
    title = doc.getitemvalue("$Title")(0)
    Print title & ": " & doc.Lastaccessed
    id = nc.Getnextnoteid(id)
Wend
```

To do the same for one particular view:

```
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim nc As NotesNoteCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim ID As String
Dim title As String
Dim view As NotesView

Set db = s.Currentdatabase
Set view = db.GetView("MyViewName")
Set nc = db.createNoteCollection(False)

Call nc.Add(view)
Call nc.Buildcollection()
id = nc.Getfirstnoteid()
While Not id = ""
    Set doc = db.Getdocumentbyid(id)
    title = doc.getitemvalue("$Title")(0)
    Print title & ": " & doc.Lastaccessed
    id = nc.Getnextnoteid(id)
Wend
```